# Solving this Differential Equation from TIFR entrance

Tags: analysis, derivatives, contest-math

The following question is from previous years' question papers of Tata Institute of Fundamental Research (TIFR) from the year 2018.[image]

I tried solving for the function f by substituting $y = x$ and trying to solve the linear Differential Equation that we get. However the solution I get is $f(0) + A x$ where $A$ is a constant. However this does not give any idea to obtain the actual solution which is option $(b)$ (as given in answer key). Can someone help me?

Comment: If you substitute $y=x$, the differential equation you get is $\color{red}{f(2x)}-f(0)=2xf'(x)$. If the left-hand side's $f(2x)$ were instead $f(x)$, then we could get a linear differential equation here, but with $f(\color{red}{2}x)$, it is not linear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't it still possible to integrate it by substituting $z=2x$ and I thought it would still be called linear.

Comment: By the way, I guess the solution I initially wrote was wrong (even thoughthe questionis still the same). I have made necessary edits.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: Maybe show us the steps in your working out, so we can see where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the given equality with respect to $x$ we get:
$$
f'(x+y)+f'(y-x)=2f'(y).
$$
Differentiating again with respect to $x$ yields:
$$
f''(x+y)-f''(y-x)=0,
$$
which implies $f''(x)=\,$constant, for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the interesting answer.